# How to programatically tell the Mac Finder to redraw a folder or file icon?

Tags: macos, caching, icons, finder

I have a process that modifies icons on files with an overlay. The Finder, though, seems to be caching the images it generates, which sometimes happens after I generate the overlay (in the case of the icon being a preview of the file instead of a plain icon).

Is there a programatic way I can tell the Finder to dump its cache for an icon image, and recreate it, without changing the file information, specifically the modification date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check: [NSWorkspace Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Refresh the Finder like this:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] noteFileSystemChanged:path];
```

Comment: I don't think this works anymore :( Can you please test it out. Can you please make a `blah.app` app bundle on your desktop with an icon. then open replace the /Contents/Resources/appicon.icns with another appicon.icns then run this. I ran it from ctypes so i might have did it wrong. Can you please verify, if you want a quick javascript code to make a app bundle and you use firefox, you can run this code form scratchpad with environment set to browser it will make app bundle on desktop: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/6a2cbe0b4c74499765be

Comment: Is there any way to do this now on OSX El Capitan and above?